# How to make hour & minute selector in angularjs using HTML5 input type 'number'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, date, datetime

So whenever user make it to 60 in minutes input type,the value of hours should be incremented by 1 and the minute counter should become 0;

so here is my code,in this hour value is incrementing but the minute value is not reseting to 0 again.What i am doing wrong in this ?or is there any better way to do ?

View:

```
<input type="number" ng-model="hoursValue">
<input type="number" ng-model="minuteValue" max="60" ng-change="callFunction(minuteValue)">
```

Controller:

```
$scope.hoursValue=0;
$scope.minuteValue=1;
  $scope.callFunction=function(minuteValue){

  if(minuteValue==60)
  {

    $scope.hoursValue= $scope.hoursValue+1;
    $scope.minuteValue=1
  }

}
```

Comment: Well this is working in plunkr, see this link https://plnkr.co/edit/Y1sIct?p=preview , and just change `$scope.minuteValue=0`. Hope this works :)

Comment: Hey thanks for Replying..Exact same code is working in plnkr but not in my code..!! Strange issue m facing !!!

Answer (score 0):

$scope already binding the value, No need to transfer the value in function.
remove 'minuteValue' in callFunction.

```
<input type="number" ng-model="minuteValue" max="60" ng-chagne="callFunction()"> 

$scope.callFunction =function() { if($scope.minuteValue== 60){ $scope.hoursValue= $scope.hoursValue+1; $scope.minuteValue=1;} }
```